# One controller/view for entities with same properties? (DRY code)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

We have quite a few lookup entities that all have the same structure - just ID and Name.  For example, Gender, Ethnicity are just dropdown lists on a Patient view.  Each lookup entity has views for viewing/adding/editing the values.  Each entity has its own controller with nearly identical actions - Index (view list), Create, and Edit.  The only thing different is the type.

Is there a way to create one controller and one set of views to manage all of these lookup entities using generics, a base entity, some other technique or a combination of these?

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` works by first initializing a instance of the model, which can't be done unless it knows the type, so using an interface or base type for your views wont work when creating/editing.

Answer (score 0):

One simple thing you can do is create an Interface for ID and Name. Then inherit it in the models that you need to.

**Example**

```
public interface IEntity 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Inherit this in your models

```
public class Gender : IEntity
{
}
```

Comment: The models are generated automatically -- I'm using database first.  The Controller and Views are what I'm hoping to be able to refactor.  Thanks for the suggestion though.